# How to put result of PDO request in JSON file

Tags: php, pdo

I write class DAO that connect to my sql server database. Now I want to execute a request et put result in JSON file and I don't see how to do it.

```
<?php 
    class DAO
    {
      // @var PDO : Attribut représentant la base de données 
      private $db;

      // Connexion à la BDD 
      function __construct()
      {
        try {
          $dsn = '192.168.102.232\SQLEXPRESS'; 
          $this->db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=192.168.102.232\SQLEXPRESS;Database=PROFACE", "username", "pwd");
          $this->db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
          exit("Erreur ouverture BD : ".utf8_encode($e->getMessage()));
        }
      }

      function getAll() {
            try {
              $request = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM PROFACE.dbo.SuiviProduction');
              $request->execute();

              $res = $request->fetchAll();
              echo $res;
            } CATCH (PDOException $e) {
              exit("Erreur getAll : ".utf8_encode($e->getMessage()));
            }
          }
    }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert something to JSON with PHP, you can use the [`json_encode`](https://php.net/json_encode) function like this:

```
$res = $request->fetchAll();
$resJSON = json_encode($res);
```

Comment: Instead of put data in a variable in json format, can I put it in a file ?

Comment: @MissKnacki sure, with `file_put_contents`